# AbsoluteTime parse two different date formats

Tags: date-and-time

I have a series of dates that regularly change format (24 hrs/12 hrs). Is there an easy way to parse this data?

`dates={"12/31/2014 11:49:23 PM", "1/01/2015 4:15", "1/01/2015 6:21", "1/01/2015 6:32", "1/01/2015 16:32"}`

I've used this code;

```
AbsoluteTime[{#, {"Month", "Day", "Year", "Hour", "Minute"}}] & /@dates
```

but it has issues with the AM/PM dates. It there an easy/clean way to try to parse the date as 12 hr time and if that doesn't work try 24 hrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** A cleaner version of `atF` below:

```
atF2 = If[StringFreeQ[#, "PM"|"AM"], 
    AbsoluteTime[{#, {"Month", "Day", "Year", "Hour", "Minute"}}], 
    AbsoluteTime[{#, {"Month", "Day", "Year", "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "AMPM"}}]] &;
atF2 /@ dates
(* {3627157763, 3629074500, 3629082060, 3629082720, 3629118720} *)
```

---

**Original post:**

`DateList` can parse mixed date strings properly:

```
dates = {"12/31/2014 11:49:23 PM", "1/01/2015 4:15", "1/01/2015 6:21",
         "1/01/2015 6:32", "1/01/2015 16:32"};

DateList /@ dates
(* {{2014, 12, 31, 23, 49, 23.}, {2015, 1, 1, 4, 15, 0.}, {2015, 1, 1, 6,
    21, 0.}, {2015, 1, 1, 6, 32, 0.}, {2015, 1, 1, 16, 32,  0.}} *)

AbsoluteTime /@ DateList /@ dates
(* {3629058563, 3629074500, 3629082060, 3629082720, 3629118720} *)
```

Or, you can do

```
atF= Quiet@Check[AbsoluteTime[{#, {"Month", "Day", "Year", "Hour", "Minute"}}], 
  AbsoluteTime[{#, {"Month", "Day", "Year", "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "AMPM"}}]]&; 
 atF/@ dates
 (* {3629058563, 3629074500, 3629082060, 3629082720, 3629118720} *)
```

Comment: True, the DateList does seem to work. I've been avoiding DateList because I found AbsoluteTime to be much faster. For my current application it doesn't seem to be an issue (only 1655 dates).

Comment: One issue I found when parsing my complete data was that I get a "date is ambiguous" warning when parsing "12/09/2014 23:06" even though the final date seems fine. Is this an issue for this approach generally?

Comment: The second approach is a little faster than the first with my data.  1.07s vs 0.87s.

Comment: @Cam, Re "ambiguous date"  warning, the only way to to fix it is to provide the date pattern `{"Month", "Day", "Year", ...}`  or `{"Day", "Month", "Year", ...}`, but then we get into a problem with mixed hour format in the data (some times in 12hr format some in 24hr). If the final result is fine, then  just using `Quiet` to suppress the warning message is the best approach. Using `AbsoluteTime` directly on date strings is better than processing the data twice.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
fixed = StringReplace[
   dates, {" " ~~ h__ ~~ ":" ~~ m__ ~~ ":" ~~ s__ ~~ " PM" :> 
     " " <> ToString[ToExpression[h] + 12] <> ":" <> m, 
    " " ~~ h__ ~~ ":" ~~ m__ ~~ ":" ~~ s__ ~~ " AM" :> 
     " " <> h <> ":" <> m}];

AbsoluteTime[{#, {"Month", "Day", "Year", "Hour", "Minute"}}] & /@ fixed

(* {3629058540,3629074500,3629082060,3629082720,3629118720,3629015340} *)
```

(I assumed seconds are not of interest, since not in your absolute time conversion and that the AM/PM all have all components)

Comment: This approach seems the fastest with my data - 0.42s.